# Injectivity of a complex function.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers

Define a map for $z\in \mathbb{C}$ , $\Im(z)>0$ as $$s=s(z)=\frac{(2z+i)^2}{4z^2-1} $$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$
**Question** Find the largest possible domain contained in $\Im(z)>0$ such that $s(z)$ is injective.

**My ideas** Let, $z$, $w\in \mathbb{C}$ be such that $$s(z)=s(w) $$
$$\frac{(2z+i)^2}{4z^2-1}=\frac{(2w+i)^2}{4w^2-1} $$ which on simplification gives $$(4zw+1)(w-z)=0 $$
So, we need a domain contained in $\Im(z)>0$ such that $(4zw+1)\neq 0$

If,  $(4zw+1)= 0$ then $zw=-\frac{1}{4}$ so that $\arg(zw)=\pi$

Hence, $\arg(z)+\arg(w)=\pi$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you define “the largest possible domain”? There are many choices, e.g. the first quadrant, the second quadrant, or all $z$ in the upper halfplane with $|z| > 1/2$.

Comment: @Martin R I mean that any subset of $\Im(z)>0$.

Comment: Yes. But as I demonstrated, there are several subsets of $\Im(z)>0$ on which the function is injective (and there are more). Which one counts as “the largest”?

Comment: @Martin R Thank you for your valuable comment. I think $|z|>1/2$ in upper half plane will work for me. Please write as an answer. I would be obliged to you

Comment: Stop creating sockpuppet accounts to evade suspension bans on your other accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notion of “largest domain on which a function is injective” is not well-defined, because injectivity on two domains  does not imply injectivity on their union.

The domain can not contain the point $z=i/2$, but otherwise there are many domains on which the function $s$ is injective, for example:

- The first quadrant $D_1 = \{ z \mid 0 < \arg z < \pi/2 \}$.
- The second quadrant $D_2 = \{ z \mid \pi/2 < \arg z < \pi \}$.
- The set $D_3 = \{ z \mid \operatorname{Im} z > 0, |z| > 1/2 \}$.

In the first two examples, the argument of $4zw$ can not be $\pi$. In the last example, $|4zw| > 1$ so that $4zw +1 \ne 0$.

Comment: Thanks a ton. A check mark for your answer.

Comment: One last question: What will be the range of argument of s?

Comment: @Mathslove: I don't know. That is a different question.

Comment: Thanks a lot....